# .NET Stackexchange.Redis : conditional delete depending on value?

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I need to delete an entry from redis cache,
But only if it matches a certain value.

If possible,I would like to avoid the overhead of first getting the value, checking on server, then deleting.

I see no option in the delete commands that I checked for restricting the delete depending on the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in Redis (regard less the choice of client and programming language) using Lua - scripts are just the thing for avoiding client-server back and forth. Here's a sample script that checks a String value for equality and deletes the key if so:

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local val = ARGV[1]
local cur = redis.call('GET', key)
if cur == val  then
  return redis.call('DEL', key)
else
  return 0
end
```

To get more insights on Lua in Redis, check out [`EVAL`'s documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval).

Comment: Thanks Itamar! This is asaf (aka 'tea guy') from thetime/emaze :)

Comment: Hey Asaf, cool bumping into you here too, and you're most welcome :)